# In R, how to use regex to look for a PATTERN of strings?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to replace a pattern in each row of my dataset with a single space.

The pattern is:
**MM/DD/YYYY ##:##:## Person Name (PNAME)**

Each row is a string like:

> [1] TEXT BEFORE... **04/17/2014 08:46:42 John Doe (JDOE)** ...TEXT AFTER

Desired results:

> [1] TEXT BEFORE... ...TEXT AFTER

I attempted it with the following (and many variations):

```
pattern <- "[[0-9]][[0-9]][[:punct:]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[:punct:]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[:space:]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[:punct:]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[:punct:]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[:space:]][[:alpha::]][[:space:]][[:alpha::]][[:punct:]][[:alpha::]][[:punct:]]) "
replacement <- " "

sub(pattern, replacement, data$Description)
```

It seems I am not setting the pattern correctly. I have read a number or regex questions on here but none that uses a pattern attempting to replace more than a single character/word. How would you write this?

Comment: You added extra brackets around `0-9`, use `[0-9]` to match a single digit

Comment: Try `gsub("\\s+\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\([^()]*\\)", "", data$Description)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJwUzm/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew THAT DID IT!!! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- `[[0-9]]` matches `[` or a digit and then a `]`, you need just `\d` or `[0-9]` to match a digit
- To match a letter you need `[[:alpha:]]` and not `[[:alpha::]]`
- You do not need to manually type several `[0-9]` or `[[:alpha:]]`, you can use `+` or limiting (range)  quantifiers (like `{1,2}`).

You can use

```r
gsub("\\s+\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\([^()]*\\)", "", data$Description)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJwUzm/1)

*Details*

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}` - date-like string (one or two digits, `/`, one or two digits, `/`, four digits)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` - time-like string
- `\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+` - two whitespace separated words enclosed with one or more whitespaces (also, can be written as `(?:\s+\w+){2}\s+`)
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.